# Generic function with different object parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I want to implement server side filtering for two data tables having different IQueryable  list

```
public IQueryable<ClassA> search(IQueryable<ClassA> query,string name,string number)
 {
    if (name!= null )
         query = query.Where( a =>a.name.Contains(name) );
    if (number!= null )
         query = query.Where( a =>a.number.ToString().Contains(numbr) );
    return query;
 }
```

and

```
public IQueryable<ClassB> search(IQueryable<ClassB> query,string address, string email)
 {
   if (address!= null )
         query = query.Where( a =>a.name.Contains(address) );
   if (email!= null )
         query = query.Where( a =>a.email.Contains(email) );
   return query;
 }
```

Since the implementation is same but ClassA and ClassB has different attributes involving different checks to search the value.

How to make a single generic function where I can perform searching with both of these classes?

Comment: I doubt generics are the way to go. make a abstract class with a abstraact "query" function. The ClassA and ClassB inherit from it. accept any AbstractClass variant.

Comment: that still requires two different functions

Comment: Could you describe what that is supposed to happen in this function? It returns void?

Comment: @RuudKobes check the code

Comment: Why do you need to have a single function for this? It seems like you're doing two different things. The only thing these methods have in common is that they contain where clauses. Making a single method for this will probably only make your code harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution, using object reflection. Parameter has two strings in pair. First is the name of property, second is the value of it.

```
 public IQueryable<T> search(IQueryable<T> query, params Tuple<string, string>[] parameters)
 {
   Type type = typeof(T);
   PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
   foreach(var parameter in parameters)
   {
     PropertyInfo pi = properties.Where(a => a.Name == parameter.Item1).FirstOrDefault();
     if (pi != null)
     {
       query = query.Where(a => pi.GetValue(a).ToString().Contains(parameter.Item2));
     }
   }

   return query;
 }
```

Comment: meets the requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can make both clases of the same interface IPropertyWalker for example. It should have thestring indexer.

```
public string this[string key]
{
    switch(key)
    {
        case "Name"
            return Name;        
        //list all you need for your class
    }
}
```

And then pass property names to compare data.

Answer (score -1):

Improving on @wannadreams response, you can lookup property information only if member type of the target is a property. Here is a full example.

```
        class ClassA
        {
            // Will work
            public string Name { get; set; }
            // Will not work
            public string Name;
        }

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IQueryable<ClassA> query = ...
            search(query, Tuple.Create(nameof(ClassA.Name), "myName"));
        }

        public static IQueryable<T> search<T>(
            IQueryable<T> query,
            params Tuple<string, string>[] parameters)
            where T : class
        {
            foreach(var criteria in parameters) {
                var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(criteria.Item1);
                if (property == null) continue;
                // you also need to verify the property was retrievable from the instance.
                query = query.Where(item => property.GetValue(item) != null)
                    .Where(item => property.GetValue(item).ToString().Contains(criteria.Item2));
            }

            return query;
        }
```